# R.id not resolving

Tags: android, android-videoview

I added a video view to one of app pages and when i try and identify it by doing R.id.videoview) the .id does not resolve. Can someone please help me?

```
package jslsoftware.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Uri vidFile = Uri.parse("http://jslserver1.yolasite.com/resources/3gp_videos/Animal.3gp");
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView)
    videoView.setVideoURI(vidFile);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.start();


}
```

}

Comment: Is it `R.id` that does not resolve, or `R.id.VideoView`?

Comment: did you add an android:id tag to the view?

Comment: include jslsoftware.com.R and it will resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put another ID for this view ? like "testName" ?
Did you check if your xml file has saved ?
The project haven't errors ?

I think you always have to edit the ID after put this view on the "form", if you don't do this you can't identify it using R.id....

Comment: Thank you very much That was exactly the problem. Also do you know what I could do to make the video appear faster on my app like having the videos start to download when the app opens. Thanks, Scott Lounsbury